# Python Class related error?

Tags: python, class

I have defined a simple class.

```
class Person:

    age = 0
    name = ''


    def __init__(self,personAge,personName):
        self.age = personAge
        self.name= personName

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


d = Person(24,'ram')
print(d)
```

so o/p is coming like this `<__main__.Person object at 0x0000020256652CF8>` .But i want o/p like this `ram`. How can i get this?

please be correcting me.Thnaks in adavance

Comment: Improve your identation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your indentation is wrong. Your overrided **str** inside **init** (constructor). Also you don't have to specify class variables if you are getting/initialising the variables through constrcutor.
try below,
`

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self,personAge,personName):
        self.age = personAge
        self.name= personName

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


d = Person(24,'ram')
print(d)
```

`

Comment: please accept it as answer if it had solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the class object, not return value of the method (see last line here). Possible indentation issue for `__str__()` method fixed, too.

```
class Person:

    age = 0
    name = ''


    def __init__(self,personAge,personName):
        self.age = personAge
        self.name= personName

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


d = Person(24,'ram')
print(d.__str__())
```

See also [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

```
    class Person:
         age = 0
         name = '' 

        def __init__(self, personAge, personName): 
              self.age = personAge
              self.name= personName 

        def __str__(self): 
               return self.name 

d = Person(24,'ram') 
print(d)
```

`__str__` should be out of `__init__` scope